# Using python to generate a JWT raises ValueError "Could not deserialize key data"

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt

I am trying to generate a JWT for a Github app following these instructions https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-json-web-token-jwt-for-a-github-app

This is what I did:

Install Python3

Pip3 install jwt

I created a pem file that has the RSA PRIVATE KEY

I copied the code from the link above and created a get-jwt.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import jwt
import time
import sys

# Get PEM file path
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    pem = sys.argv[1]
else:
    pem = input("Enter path of private PEM file: ")

# Get the App ID
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    app_id = sys.argv[2]
else:
    app_id = input("Enter your APP ID: ")

# Open PEM
with open(pem, 'rb') as pem_file:
    signing_key = jwt.jwk_from_pem(pem_file.read())

payload = {
    # Issued at time
    'iat': int(time.time()),
    # JWT expiration time (10 minutes maximum)
    'exp': int(time.time()) + 600,
    # GitHub App's identifier
    'iss': app_id
}

# Create JWT
jwt_instance = jwt.JWT()
encoded_jwt = jwt_instance.encode(payload, signing_key, alg='RS256')

print(f"JWT:  ", encoded_jwt)
```

When I do `python3 get-jwt.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/al/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/jwt/jwk.py", line 345, in jwk_from_private_bytes
    privkey = private_loader(content, password, backend)  # type: ignore[operator]  # noqa: E501
  File "/Users/al/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 24, in load_pem_private_key
    return ossl.load_pem_private_key(
  File "/Users/al/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 957, in load_pem_private_key
    return self._load_key(
  File "/Users/al/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1152, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/Users/al/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1207, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had no problems running that script, I generated a pem key with the command: `openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem`

Comment: It worked after I did that open ssl command to generate the cert.pem. Please feel free to list this as an answer and I will select that as the right one. This was my bad.